# Casting Java Objects From JRuby

Tags: casting, jruby

I'm working with a Java library in JRuby.  I'm reading an object from a file, and I need to pass it as a different object type to a second constructor:

```
@hmm_model = ObjectInputStream.new(FileInputStream.new(LINGPIPE_MODEL_PATH))
@tagger = HmmDecoder.new(@hmm_model)
```

@hmm_model is of type ObjectInputStream, and needs to be cast to (HiddenMarkovModel).  Obviously, that'd be easy in Java, it would just be:

```
@tagger = HmmDecoder.new((HiddenMarkovModel)@hmm_model)
```

But, of course, that doesn't work in JRuby.  Is there actually any way to explicitly cast the @hmm_model to be of the correct type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I'm not very bright.  The JRuby JVM interface is smart enough to cast itself, I was making the call to the constructor incorrectly.  The actual call is:

```
@tagger = HmmDecoder.new(@hmm_model.readObject())
```

and JRuby correctly handles the type conversion to a HiddenMarkovModel.

JRuby: 1
me: 0