# Casting objects in JRuby

Tags: java, casting, jruby, jruby-java-interop

Is there a way I can explicitly cast one Java object to another Java class from JRuby?

Sometimes I want to be able to invoke `SomeJavaClass#aMethod(MySuperClass)` rather than `SomeJavaClass#aMethod(MyClass)` from JRuby.

From Java, I'd do this:

```
someJavaObject.aMethod( (MySuperClass) myObj );
```

but I didn't see a `#cast` ruby method or anything like that to do the equivalent from JRuby.

**Note** that the question [Casting Java Objects From JRuby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548565/casting-java-objects-from-jruby) lacks an answer for the general case, which is why I'm re-asking the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to make use of either the `#java_send` or `#java_alias` feature available starting with JRuby 1.4 to select the method you wish to call. Example:

```ruby
class Java::JavaUtil::Arrays
  boolean_array_class = [false].to_java(:boolean).java_class
  java_alias :boolean_equals, :equals, [boolean_array_class, boolean_array_class]
end

a1 = [false, true]
Java::JavaUtil::Arrays.boolean_equals a1, a1
# => TypeError: for method Arrays.equals expected [class [Z, class [Z]; got: [org.jruby.RubyArray,org.jruby.RubyArray]; error: argument type mismatch
Java::JavaUtil::Arrays.boolean_equals a1.to_java(:boolean), a1.to_java(:boolean)
# => true
a2 = [true, false]
Java::JavaUtil::Arrays.boolean_equals a1.to_java(:boolean), a2.to_java(:boolean)
# => false
```

Comment: I think it would be useful to add that if you're trying to cast to non-primitive classes, you should use the full hierarchy. So, say, to to cast `obj` to `ij.text.TextWindow` class, you'd have to write `obj.to_java(Java::Ij::text::TextWindow)`.